# Prove that $a^2$ when divided by $5$ cannot have a remainder of $3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, square-numbers, quadratic-residues

For any natural number $a$, prove that $a^2$ when divided by $5$ cannot have a remainder of $3$. (Hint: What are the possible values of the remainder when $a$ is divided by $5$?

Using the hint, I found that the possible values of the remainder are $1, 2, 3, 4$, and $0$, and $3$ is only a remainder when the last digit of $a$ is $3$ or $8$.

But I'm not sure how to explain this in a proof, and I don't know how to extend it to $a^2$. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The sequence of squares $\pmod{10}$ is given by $$0,1,4,9,6,5,9,1,0,1,4,9,6,5,\ldots $$ Do you see any $3$ or $8$?

Comment: I understand that there is no a^2 with 3 or 8 as the last digit, but I am unsure how to state this in a formal proof.

Comment: The sequence of squares $\pmod{5}$ has period $5$. If no square among $0^2,1^2,2^2,3^2,4^2$ is $\equiv 3\pmod{5}$, no integer square is $\equiv 3\pmod{5}$.

Comment: Try to get away from the crutch of relying on base 10.  It's not wrong but it's weak and not versatile. a/5 will have remainder 0,1,2,3,4.  If you scare a the remainder will be 0,1,4,5 or 1 and never 2 or 3.  (a=5b+r so a^2 = (5b+r)^2 = 25b^2+10br +r^2 and r^2 =0,1,4,9, or 16....so....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are unfamiliar with modular arithmetic, then this might help: If the remainder of $\frac a5$ is $1$, that is another way of saying that there is an integer $r$ such that $a=5r+1$. Squaring both sides, we get $$a^2=(5r+1)^2=25r^2+10r+1=5(5r^2+2r)+1$$which means that the remainder of $\frac{a^2}5$ is also $1$.

Doing the same thing for the other four possibilities will tell you that the remainder is never $3$.

Note that this is *exactly* the same as the modular arithmetic approach, only phrased in what is hopefully more accessible language.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

if $a \equiv 0 \mod 5$, then $a^2 \equiv 0 \mod 5$.

if $a \equiv 1 \mod 5$, then $a^2 \equiv 1 \mod 5$.

if $a \equiv 2 \mod 5$, then $a^2 \equiv 4 \mod 5$.

if $a \equiv -2 \mod 5$, then $a^2  \equiv 4 \mod 5$.

if $a \equiv -1 \mod 5$, then $a^2 \equiv 1 \mod 5$.

Answer (score 1):

Any integer $a \equiv 0,\pm1,\pm2 \pmod 5$. Since $2^2=4 \equiv -1 \pmod 5$ it follows that $a^2 \equiv 0, \pm 1 \pmod 5$. This proves both that $a^2 \not \equiv 3 \pmod 5$ which was the original question, and also that $a^2 \not \equiv 2 \pmod 5$ for a bonus conclusion.